# Parse Youtube atom feeds on Ruby

Tags: ruby, youtube-api, atom-feed, feedzirra

I use http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/1i8s245jxRE which return an atom feed to get statistics from youtube. It works in Python using `feedparser`. Is there any equivalent gem to do it in Ruby?

I tried `simple-rss` and get `SimpleRSSError: Poorly formatted feed`. I also tried `feedzirra` and it return a `nil` object?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you forgot open the feed?

```
rss = SimpleRSS.parse(open(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "public/............./feed.xml"))
```

maybe you need: require 'open-uri'